# having issue with environment deployment branches on Github using terraform

Tags: github, automation, terraform, devops, github-api

I'm trying to set some restriction for github_repository_deployment_branch_policy using terraform
but it is not working properly and my rules are not being applied,

```
resource "github_repository_deployment_branch_policy" "deployment_branch_policy" {
  repository       = "repo"
  environment_name = "name"
  name             = "main_name"
}
```

I would like to know is what should I do so i can apply those rules for environment deployment branches to be change from all branches to just selected with terraform

Thanks in advance

I tried using step by step guide from documentation but I received 404 error from their API

Answer (score 0):

Did you create github environment first? Example from the docs:

```
resource "github_repository_environment" "env" {
  repository  = "my_repo"
  environment = "my_env"
  deployment_branch_policy {
    protected_branches     = false
    custom_branch_policies = true
  }
}
```

Specifically, you need to declare **custom_branch_policies = true**

Remember to add depends_on in deployment_branch_policy, like this:

```
resource "github_repository_deployment_branch_policy" "deployment_branch_policy" {
  depends_on = [github_repository_environment.env]
  repository       = "repo"
  environment_name = "name"
  name             = "main_name"
}
```